checkNotNull vs. JEP 358: Helpful NullPointerExceptions: Should we remove existing null checks?
With the introduction of JEP 358 in Java 14, which provides more informative NullPointerException (NPE) messages, is it advisable to remove existing explicit null checks in cases where the null-check is straightforward?
Consider the following examples:

Simple parameter check:
 @Override
 public <T> T accept(final @Nonnull XyzMessageVisitor<T> visitor) {
     checkNotNull(visitor, "visitor cannot be null");
     return visitor.visit(this);
 }


Multiple parameters checked at the start of a method:
 @Nonnull
 public static BitSet toIncomingChanges(final @Nonnull XyzPayload oldData, 
         final @Nonnull XyzPayload newData) {
     checkNotNull(oldData, "oldData cannot be null");
     checkNotNull(newData, "newData cannot be null");

     final int oldDataLength = oldData.getDataLength();
     final int newDataLength = newData.getDataLength();

     ...
 }



(checkNotNull is from Guava's Preconditions.)
What are the pros and cons of relying on JEP 358's enhanced NPE messages and removing these explicit null checks?

Your title is a bit misleading. Your checkNotNull() raises an exception just like the JVM would do anyway, just with a better error message. Clearly it doesn't matter whether you use your own exception messages or new platform exception messages. But a "check" more often means code that checks for null and then avoids the exception - and those of course shouldn't be removed.

Which @Nonnull are you importing here?

@candied_orange: javax.annotation.Nonnull from Guava's com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305 dependency.

In a code review, an explicit null check would show me that you've thought about this possibility. If you remove this check, it is no longer as clear what you've designed for. In simple cases the method will still raise an NPE, but maybe only later after some side effects have already happened. In your concrete examples, I'd leave the NonNull annotation but might remove the check, because the objects are accessed before any side effects happen.

Reading JEP 358 makes it seem like your code is a poor example of making use of what's been added in Java 14.
The primary discussion is about chains (x.y.z.length()) and showing which one was null. Your code has no such chain.
I'd still like to see the names removed from checkNotNull because it impedes use of refactoring tools to rename oldData and newData without having to search inside strings.
Never make refactoring harder than it needs to be.

Thanks for the answer! About names: I've found that (in Java 13 and earlier) including names in checkNotNull can simplify debugging. Even if parameter names aren't updated after renaming, they’re still more helpful than an NPE with an empty message. This also avoids misleading line numbers that can occur due to code or line changes between production and main branch versions.
